# Why doesnt it show the path?

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

I am trying to show the path taken for this Dijkstra's algo, however, once the program ends, it should display the path taken and how many steps it has taken. But it only shows the end_pos and 1 step I have looked over the code multiple times but maybe im too tired to recognise the mistake or im just stupid.... Anyone have any idea?

```
# imports go here


class DijkstraPathfinder:
    @staticmethod
    def find_path():
        def _get_start_and_end_pos():
            start_pos, end_pos = None, None
            for row in grid:
                for square in row:
                    if square.state == SquareState.START:
                        start_pos = square.row, square.col
                    elif square.state == SquareState.END:
                        end_pos = square.row, square.col

            return start_pos, end_pos

        def _get_valid_neighbours(r: int, c: int):
            """
            Find valid neighbours for a square:
            valid means it's not a wall, has not been visited
            :param r: row
            :param c: column
            :return: valid neighbours
            :rtype: list()
            """

            up_neighbour = (r, c + 1)
            down_neighbour = (r, c - 1)
            left_neighbour = (r - 1, c)
            right_neighbour = (r + 1, c)

            neighbours = [up_neighbour, down_neighbour, left_neighbour, right_neighbour]
            v_neighbours = list()

            for neighbour in neighbours:
                r, c = neighbour
                if r in range(settings.ROWS) and c in range(settings.ROWS):
                    if grid[r][c].state not in [SquareState.VISITED, SquareState.WALL, SquareState.START]:
                        v_neighbours.append(neighbour)

            return v_neighbours

        def _reconstruct_path():
            path = [end_pos]
            current = end_pos

            while prev[current]:
                path.append(prev[current])
                current = prev[current]
                # print(u)

            path.reverse()
            return path

        WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
        grid = Creator.get_grid()

        start_pos, end_pos = _get_start_and_end_pos()

        print()
        print(f'Starting position: {start_pos}')
        print(f'Ending position: {end_pos}')
        print()

        dist = {}
        prev = {}
        q = list()

        finished = False

        while not finished:

            for row in grid:
                for square in row:
                    pos = square.get_pos()

                    dist[square.get_pos()] = float("inf")
                    prev[square.get_pos()] = None
                    if square.state in [SquareState.EMPTY, SquareState.START, SquareState.END]:
                        q.append(pos)

            dist[start_pos] = 0

            while q:
                u = min(q, key=dist.__getitem__)
                q.remove(u)

                for v in _get_valid_neighbours(*u):
                    alt = dist[u] + 1

                    if alt < dist[v]:
                        dist[v] = alt
                        prev[v] = u

                        vr, vc = v
                        grid[vr][vc].change_state(SquareState.VISITED)

                    if v == end_pos:
                        q = list()
                        break

                picasso.draw(WINDOW, grid)
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        finished = True
                        q = list()
                        break

            path = _reconstruct_path()

            for square in path:
                row, col = square
                grid[row][col].change_state(SquareState.PATH)
                picasso.draw(WINDOW, grid)
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        finished = True
                        break

        print(f'Path found, took {len(path)} moves')
        print(f'Moves: {path}')
        print()

        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DijkstraPathfinder.find_path()
```

I Have tried to change this up, especially the last prints but it seems that it still does the same thing, where it only shows that "Path found, took 1 moves" and then below it shows "Moves: end_pos" where end_pos is wherever you had placed your final point.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation where you iterate over the neighbours:

```py
for v in _get_valid_neighbours(*u)
```

You don't append anything to `q`, so the iteration stops there. As a result, in `_reconstruct_path()`, there is no `prev` node for the end point, and you get the path length as one.